# Linker Scripts: Can I specify (*COMMON) in more than one section?

Tags: gcc, stm32, gnu, cortex-m, linker-scripts

If I have two sections in my linker script, .bss and .newsect, can I include (*COMMON) in both like I have done below? Why or why not?

```
  .bss :
  {
    /* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .bss section */
    _sbss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss start */
    __bss_start__ = _sbss;
    *(.bss)
    *(.bss*)
    *(COMMON)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ebss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss end */
    __bss_end__ = _ebss;
  } >RAM_D1

  .newsect :
  {
    /* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .bss section */
    _snewsect = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss start */
    __newsect_start__ = _snewsect;
    *(.newsect)
    *(.newsect*)
    *(COMMON)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _enewsect = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss end */
    __newsect_end__ = _enewsect;
  } >RAM_D1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not do any harm, but all the matching input sections will have already been allocated to output sections by the first time you specify them so the second time will not match anything and will do nothing.

Comment: @Ryan Murphy, if this solves you question can you please accept the answer with the tick mark on the left.